# Is there an item limit on a picture library slideshow web part?

Tags: picture

I have a picture library slideshow web part displaying photos and it is looping after 300, although there are 700+ items in the view...can this be fixed?

Comment: Here is a MS article that explains the limits:                             http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx                                    you should not have any issues with 700+ items.

Answer (score 2):

The OOTB PictureLibrarySlideshow Web Part has some wierd logic that if the Picture Display Mode is Sequential then it'll max show 300 pictures if it's Random then it'll show up to 1500